# A little help with Derangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

In the textbook I'm using to train Olympic combinatorics **Combinatorial problems in Mathematical competitions** by *Yao Zhang* there is a problem which I personally found peculiarly interesting the Euler-Bernoulli misaddressed letter problem:

> How many ways to distribute $n$ distinct letters into $n$ envelops so that no letter gets to its corresponding envelop?

At first I didn't get the points and they I tried different things of what I've learned, I couldn't go farther and eventually looked at the solution, but there are things I couldn't understand at all.

The solution said that what we wanted to count was actually how many permutations of $\{1,2, \cdots, n\}$ there are such that $k$ is not at the $k^{th}$ place for any $1 \le k \le n$. And that these permutations are called derangements. Also said that this kind of permutations are permutations with not fixed point.

I know that this might be something not so difficult but I really get kind of confuse. Can someone tell with a little more detail what does it mean that stuff of permutations (With/without) fixed points?

Going a little further in the solution we set as $S$ the set of all permutations of $\{1,2, \cdots , n\} $ and $A_{i}$ the set of permutations $\{a_{1},a_{2}, \cdots , a_{n}\} $ of $\{1,2, \cdots , n\} $ satisfying $a_{i} = i$ $( i = 1,2,3 ... n)$. So, I can understand this because you can use *The sieve formula* to get exactly the the intersection of the complement of all the sets in which the $k_{th}$ permutation is in the $k_{th}$ place.

What I can't understand very well is the cardinalities of $A_{i}$'s sets, for example how do you know that $\lvert A_{i} \rvert = (n-1)!$, $ \lvert A_{i} \cup A_{j} \rvert = (n-2)!$ or even that $ \lvert A_{i_{1}} \cup A_{i_{2}} \cup \cdots \cup  A_{i_{k}} \rvert = (n-k)! $ for $ ( 1 \le i_{1} < i_{2}< \cdots < i_{k} \le n)$. I will show you the solution anyways, to help you understand better what I'm trying to ask for.

[image]

Any help, idea or correction will be welcome! Thanks for your time and attention (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say we want to calculate $|A_1|$. What's that? The number of ways to permute $1,2,\ldots,n$ such that the first term is $1$. Well, the first term is fixed, and we can freely permute the remaining $n-1$ numbers in $(n-1)!$ ways. The same goes for the other numbers; in calculating $|A_i|$ one of the terms is fixed and the remaining $n-1$ terms are permuted freely in $(n-1)!$ ways.

While calculating $|A_1\cap A_2|$, we have now fixed the first and second term. How many terms remain? Well, $n-2$ of them which can be permuted in $(n-2)!$ ways. I think you can see now how this and the further terms generalise.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Everything is cleaner now my friend, and it wasn't so difficult as I thought. Thanks a lot  for your help:)